Tensiometer Equations
I'm developing a concept for measuring fiberglass strand tension. The basic concept of the machine is that we tension the strands first, and then we measure the tension.
In the part where we measure the tension, I decided to use the tensiometer approach - similar that it is used for measuring steel wire tension on the field.
I will design a three-pulley system, and in the middle pulley, we will measure the force FLC with a load cell. From that measurement we will have a constant to get to force FS - strand tension.
Now I ask if there is any simpler way to get to the final result. I tried as much as I could, but if someone sees a better way to get to the final solution, I kindly ask for help. I always like as clean solutions as possible, but I don't see them always.

